# Get table td input values corresponding to id

Tags: jquery, webgrid

i need to change value for all `td's` how can i all `td` under tr

i have `DISReferralId` `27` ... by this id how to filter

**code :**

```
<tr class="alter-bgcolor">
     <td class="grid_normal_column">42423</td>
        <td class="grid_normal_column">Etet Eryrytry</td>
        <td class="grid_normal_column">17/03/2014</td>
        <td class="grid_normal_column">No</td>
        <td class="grid_normal_column">No</td>
        <td class="grid_normal_column"></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="DISReferralId" id="27" value="27"></td>
        <td class="grid_normal_column">New</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: You want to get the value if the input?

Comment: HI edited the question pls check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the input element:

- using `name`attribute:

  ```
  var elem = $('input[name="DISReferralId"]');
  ```
- using `value`attribute:

  ```
  var elem = $('input[value="27"]');
  ```
- using both `name` and `value` attributes:

  ```
  var elem = $('input[name="DISReferralId"][value="27"]');
  ```
- using `id` attribute:

  ```
  var elem = $('#27');
  // or
  var elem = $('input[id="27"]');
  ```

Then to get all tds of the row containing that input:

```
                 parent    parent
                   td       tr        all tds
                    |        |           |
                    \/       \/          \/
var alltds = elem.parent().parent().children()

// or

                 parent   all tds excepts
                   td     input parent td  add input parent td
                    |       |               |
                    \/      \/              \/
var alltds = elem.parent().siblings().addBack()
```